# I need to return result from my php function to my code

Tags: php, mysql

```
  $employee_id='E81OYKC';   // here is my employee id 

  getFileName($employee_id);  // here i am calling function

  echo $response; // here i want $response value.

  function getFileName($employee_id)
  {

      //Mysql Query to fetch data 

       $sql = mysql_query("SELECT work_experience, curr_designation from employee_registration where employee_id='$employee_id'") or die(mysql_error());

       //fetching data from server 

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
      {

        $curr_des = $row['curr_designation'];
        $work_exp = $row['work_experience'];
        $response =  $work_exp.' '.$curr_des;
        return $response;  // here is my result
      }
 }
```

//here in this code i want $response value after calling method i.e getFileName() but i am getting blank value over there.

Comment: `return` leaves a function, so your while loop will only perform one iteration, and then exit the function. You want to _append_ new content to your `$response` variable in the loop, and then return it _after_ the loop.

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: In addition to what @CBroe and @Jay Blanchard said: Just calling the function will execute what is inside and return the value, everything ok with that. But you have to store what the function returns, in a variable, in this case call it `$response`.

Answer (score 0):

Receive your response into variable then you can use it

```
 $response = getFileName($employee_id);  // here i am calling function

 echo $response;
```

Answer (score -1):

you need variable to get the response for example

```
$response = getFileName($employee_id);
```

then you `print_r` or `echo $response`

and make sure don't used `mysql_*` . you can used `mysqli_*`

i have done some changes.. try this

```
$employee_id='E81OYKC';   // here is my employee id 

      $response = getFileName($employee_id);  // here i am calling function

      echo $response; // here i want $response value.

      function getFileName($employee_id)
      {

          //Mysql Query to fetch data 

           $sql = mysql_query("SELECT work_experience, curr_designation from employee_registration where employee_id='$employee_id'") or die(mysql_error());

           //fetching data from server 

          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
          {

            $curr_des = $row['curr_designation'];
            $work_exp = $row['work_experience'];
            $response =  $work_exp.' '.$curr_des;
            return $response;  // here is my result
          }
     }
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*` functions anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: @jay Blanchard i have updated my answer with details

Comment: @Marcel i know we used mysqli_* .. but in this question he didn't used mysqli_*  and i mention that

Comment: and exactly what's the difference between your code and OP's? please help me i can see

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile at the top i mention the problem or error

Comment: oh ok now I see